# Disable Treeview Nodes

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

How to disable the treeview nodes in windows forms c#.net

Comment: Please elaborate. Describe better what you want to do. You can't "gray out" default tree nodes if that is what you want, but you can hide them or handle events so that they cannot be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to do that, best you can do is remove the node and keep track of it.

[How do I make a TreeNode not visible? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199417/how-do-i-make-a-treenode-not-visible-c)