# How do I make a TreeNode not visible? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-2.0, treenode

There is probably a really straightforward answer to this but I'm having difficulty finding it.

Simple, I have a TreeNode and I would like to make its visibility false. (or another way of not allowing it to be shown until required).

**Edit - Another Question?**

I'm confused as to how there isn't a Visible attribute but then there is the property:

```
Node.PrevVisibleNode;
```

What is the difference between this and `Node.PrevNode`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. There is an `IsVisible` property, but it is readonly and will indicate whether the node is currently visible within the client area of the `TreeView` control. I think you will need to remove it from the nodes collection in which it resides (and optionally remember the position of it to be able to restore it.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... I originally (and incorrectly) mentioned `IsVisible`. However, on inspection I expect the answer is simply: don't add it until you need it.

This is easier if your UI model is an abstraction *above* your actual data model, so you can store items in the data model *regardless* of their visibility, and simply update the UI (add/remove/update nodes) as necessary.

Comment: I have a question thanks if you could give me answer on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077785/how-to-implement-disable-functionality (Sorry but this is the only way i found to contact you because you had answered few of my questions before also).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. You'll have to remove the node.

Answer (score -1):

> Node.PrevVisibleNode;

I think this means visible as in it's visible to the user (all parent nodes are expanded)